# Strip element of Knockout binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Quick question that I am probably just having a hard time asking correctly and therefore having a hard time figuring out how to accomplish this -

http://jsfiddle.net/RsKUS/

When I click on the div I want to take one action but if there is a button nested inside the div I only want to perform that action, not both.

```
<div data-bind="click: clickOne">
    <p>It's here too...</p>
    <button data-bind="click: clickTwo">Child</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `clickBubble: false` on the inner handler to prevent the click event bubbling:

```
<div data-bind="click: clickOne">
    <p>It's here too...</p>
    <button data-bind="click: clickTwo, clickBubble: false">Child</button>
</div>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VwcnL/).

See also in the `click` binding documentation: [Note 4: Preventing the event from bubbling](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html)

Comment: Thanks man that did it.  - 3 minutes til I can save as answer